# Error during Hibernate connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, struts2

Struts Problem Report

```
Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
Messages:   
Error! Please, check your JDBC/JDNI Configurations and Database Server avaliability. Could not open or put a Hibernate Session in ValueStack: JDBC Driver class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
File:   com/googlecode/s2hibernate/struts2/plugin/interceptors/SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java
Line number:    134
JDBC Driver class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
```

I have kept MySQL jar in lib and have checked in ref lib all are correct please         suggest me ho to solve this issue I am trying to connect db by Hibernate annotation

Stacktraces

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: Error! Please, check your JDBC/JDNI Configurations and Database Server avaliability. Could not open or put a Hibernate Session in ValueStack: JDBC Driver class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
```

Comment: I have added mysql jar in lib and have all reffrenced classes

Comment: Please, post your hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong driver class configured. The correct class name `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. See the example of usage [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/).

Comment: Thankyou sir, Same prob was there we solved it same day